# Error request for member 'quantidade' in 'b.Estoque::nome', which is of non-class type 'char [60]'

Tags: c++

bom dia, estou com esse erro de **request for member** no meu float, alguem poderia ajudar?

```
struct Estoque {   
char nome[60];   
char quantidade[60];   
char preco[60]; 
};

float caixaAtual = 0.00; 
float venda(); 
void consultarSaldo();

float venda() {   
Estoque b;   
int qtd;   
float lucro = 0;   
char a;   
do {
    cout << "Informe o nome do produto:\n";
    cin >> b.nome;
    if (b.nome.quantidade < 0) {

      cout << "Produto indisponivel\n";
    } else {
      cout << "Informe a quantidade:\n";
      cin >> qtd;
      cout << "Produto:\n" << b.nome.nome;
      cout << "Quantidade:\n" << qtd;
      cout << "Preço:\n" << b.nome.preco;
      cout << "SubTotal:\n" << b.nome.preco * qtd;
      lucro += b.nome.preco * qtd;
      b.nome.quantidade -= qtd;
    }
    cout << "Deseja vender mais um item? (1) sim (2) não";
    cin >> a;   } while (a != '2');

  cout << "\t\t\t Total: %1.2f" << lucro;

  return lucro; 
}
```

Comment: Os erros são de sintaxe veja que você não declarou valor de `b.nome` e ainda duplicou `b.nome.nome`

Comment: Este código é extremamente confuso e não faz o menor sentido, provavelmente porque falta partes (não que eu ache que você não colocou tudo, apenas que colou coisas quase aleatórias e acha que isso vai produzir algo útil), então nem sei o que fazer você não tem um erro pontual só consigo recomendar mais o assunto, entender como se programa algo assim e começar de novo. Não é um erro de programação de fato, é um erro do problema não estar bem definido antes de qualquer coisa. E o código mistura C com C++, então tem muita coisa para consertar. Sim, existe erro pontual também, mas ñ é só,ñ resolve

Comment: Qual o sentido de você declarar quantidade e preço como string de caracteres?